# Modify properties of a div within a specific div

Tags: html, css

I have a page that displays all posts that have general stack of nested divs (header-div, footer-div, etc.) for each, however, for a specific post I'd like to hide the footer-div. Each post has an id, and header-div and footer-div are class names.

For example, if I want to hide the footer-div for div id=123, I tried

```
#div123 .footer-div {
    display: none;
}
```

It doesn't seem to work.

Doing this code however will hide all footer-divs which I don't want.

```
.footer-div {
    display: none;
}
```

How does one do that? Is that even possible?
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: add your HTML code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your `class` and `ID` same level then remove `space` like

```
#div123.footer-div {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: IT WORKS. I had to put the space like you said, because it's the same level. Thank you.